# How to apply decimal format to a Userform Textbox entry?

Tags: excel, vba

I want my Price Text Box to have decimal format so when a user types `1000000` it shows `1.000.000`.

I tried the code below but it doesn't show the decimal format in Price Textbox.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    tbPrice.Text = Format(Number, "0.000")
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are updating the value on `ForUserForm_Initializem()` which will only update once the User form is loaded for first time. So in order to update the value which user enters into the textbox, you have to use `AfterUpdate()`

```vb
Private Sub tbPrice_AfterUpdate()
    tbPrice.Text = Format(tbPrice.Text, "0.000")
End Sub
```

This function will called every time the user updates the value in the textbox - `tbPrice`

Comment: how if i want it while user is typing, i tried your code but the decimal only shows when user finish inserting number on the textbox

Comment: For that you can use `tbPrice_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)` function but then you have to write some logic to handle the keypress on every input the user will type in.

Comment: @Justinjant Easy way out will be to enter `0.000` as a default value or on load of the textbox.